# how to set a string array name as a varible

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, variables

I am trying to make place dropdowns for user locations in my app. I'm using Exposed Drop-Down Menu not spinners. I've set it up so that depending on which country you have your self set to, it changes the next dropdown to reflect that.

this is how I do it:

```
        val country= resources.getStringArray(R.array.nations)
        val arrayadapters = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.country_dropdown, country)
        view.autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayadapters)

        view.autoCompleteTextView2.setOnClickListener {
            val abc = autoCompleteTextView.text.toString()

            if(abc == "canada"){
                var country2= resources.getStringArray(R.array.canada)
                val arrayadapters2 = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.locality_dropdown, country2 )
                view.autoCompleteTextView2.setAdapter(arrayadapters2)
            }

            if (abc == "us"){
                var country2 = resources.getStringArray(R.array.american_states)
                val arrayadapters2 = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.locality_dropdown, country2)
                view.autoCompleteTextView2.setAdapter(arrayadapters2)
            }
}
```

anyways this takes what country you have selected and depending on that gives you a drop-down of all the regions within that country

the problem that I'm having is that of code scalability, I don't think It would be wise or reasonable to copy, paste and modify for each and every locality.

so my question is this. how do you set the name of the string array to a variable so I can have 1 line of code and just switch out the name of the location and have it read the string array that way.

if you're wondering the string array is `XML` stored int the `res\values\strings.xml` as something like this

```
<string-array name="canada">
    <item>Alberta</item>
    <item>British Columbia</item>
    <item>Manitoba</item>
    <item>New Brunswick</item>
    <item>Newfoundland and Labrador</item>
    <item>Nova Scotia</item>
    <item>Nunavut</item>
    <item>Ontario</item>
    <item>Prince Edward Island</item>
    <item>Northwest Territories</item>
    <item>Quebec</item>
    <item>Saskatchewan</item>
    <item>Yukon</item>
</string-array>
```

thank you for reading my question, if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Your string comparisons need .equals() rather than ==, though that is not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: That's not correct @something. This is written in Kotlin, not Java (although it's been mis-tagged as Java too).

Comment: it works without it, can you show me what that would entail with .equals(). I can't see where .equals() would really go

Comment: @HenryTwist java is both interoperable with kotlin and android studio will re-wright your java code to kotlin and maybe the other way around.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm not sure how that's relevant to my comment?

Comment: I was misled by the 'java' tag, which has since been removed.  Closer attention to the 'val' keywords would have clued me in.

Comment: Perfect example of why tags are so important, incorrect ones confuse everyone!

Comment: my bad but can someone please help me

Answer (score -1):

Edited: this was a Java solution, since question was originally tagged as asking about Java.  Don't spray language tags at random.

This is what maps are for.  A sketch of an approach, rather than full code, follows.

The setup:

```
class CountryStuff {
    Country country;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ...etc...
    CountryStuff(Country c, ArrayAdapter a, ...etc...) {
       country = c;
       adapter = a;
       ...etc...
    }
}

Map<String,CountryStuff> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("canada", new CountryStuff(...whatever...);
map.put("us", new CountryStuff(...whatever...);
```

The use:

```
String abc = "something"; // country name as determined before
CountryStuff stuff = map.get(abc);
if (stuff == null) {
  ... no such country ...
}
else {
    country2 = stuff.country;
    adapter2 = stuff.adapter;
       ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: Despite this being in the wrong language, isn't the approach correct?  You need a structure that allows you to find some arbitrary data by a key.  You preferably don't want to do linear searches in an array, and you definitely don't want a cascade of if-then-elses, one for each possible key.  So what's the kotlin approach?

Comment: I have a method of getting the array but it's kind of awkward. I also need it done in a certain way for the Exposed Drop-Down Menu. really what I need is for the country in the `(R.array.canada)` to be a variable so it would look something like this `(R.array.variable)`. right now I would need to write basically the same line of code like 400 times. I don't want to do that because I don't have the time and am worried about code maintainability and size

Comment: my java is also a bit rusty so I am having a hard time following your code, my fault not yours. thanks for the answer

Comment: If any kotlin programmer wants to take my answer and turn it into their own kotlin answer, please feel free to do so.

Comment: I dont even think that would work due the the fact that it only want a certain kind of value

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. What is the "it" than wants a "certain kind"?  What kind?    But as a practicing Java programmer, I'd say not a week goes by without me using a map for this sort of thing.